# kanji composition question -- why these radicals for 出?

Tags: kanji, radicals

My explanatory Kanji dictionary lists 山 and 冂 as radicals used in 出. I see how the first one would be used, but cannot understand the reasoning for the second one.

I see two alternatives:

- 冂 is used to give the reading of 出

Or, more likely

- I don't fully understand the idea behind radicals :-)

Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just the opinion of your dictionary. According to the KRADFILE, 出 has these radicals:

```
#
#                           K R A D F I L E
#
#       Copyright 2001/2005 Michael Raine, James Breen and the Electronic
#       Dictionary Research & Development Group at Monash University.
#       See: http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/groups/edrdg/licence.html
#       for permissions for use and redistribution.
[ ... big snip ... ]
出 : ｜ 山
[ ... bigger snip ... ]
```

So, "vertical stick" and mountain are the radicals according to this source, which is located here: http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/kradinf.html

Actually, a better terminology is radical plus components. A kanji is understood to have one primary component. This is called the radical. The others are components.

So kradfile says ｜ is the radical, and the kanjidic agrees. The latter states that this character has the No. 2 radical. This No. 2 refers to the Kang-Xi 214 radical index.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Kangxi_radicals . Here you can learn the name of that No. 2 stick in Chinese and Japanese.

Wictionary assigns a different radical from Kanjidic: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%87%BA . They cite Radical No. 17, 凵 . This opinion is justifiable. When we draw the kanji, we make that shape first, then the vertical line, and then the bottom box.

Offline source: Jack Halpern's *The Kodansha Kanji Learner's Dictionary* sides with Wictionary: it assigns Radical 17 also.

Unicode Unihan data: http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=51FA
Radical 17, again.

However, 冂 as a radical or component of 出? Nonsensical. Perhaps a typo.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer says,「冂」is definitely not a component of「出」.

「出」originally depicted something very simple: a foot「止」exiting out of a cave「凵」, indicating the meaning *exit*. Unfortunately, the shape has changed too much over the years to make this construction obvious nowadays.

## <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]

[合集10405](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=10405&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
頌壺
[集成9731](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9731&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
[image]
[說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
　<kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
[睡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)ㆍ[雜](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/qinwenzi/reference/reference)</kbd>
　<kbd>現代
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

For reference,

## <kbd>商
甲
[image]

[合集33193](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=33193&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
金
[image]
琱生簋
[集成4292](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4292&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>秦
簡
[image: ![enter image description here]
睡ㆍ[為](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/qinwenzi/reference/reference)</kbd>
　<kbd>現代
楷
[image]</kbd>